# regexp split span

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split myText in
`<span id = 'sHint' class = 'numberCircleGreenShadow'>1</span>` and in
`<span id = 'sHint' class = 'numberCircleGreenShadow'>2</span>` so that I get
test1 and test2.

I wrote the next code but it does not work.
Could you please someone help me on my mistake.

The other option is to remove them entirely, but I couldn't find if something like that is possible.

```
<script>
    myText = "<span id = 'sHint' class = 'numberCircleGreenShadow'>1</span>test1<span id = 'sHint' class = 'numberCircleGreenShadow'>2</span>test2"
    
    re = new RegExp((<span id = 'sHint' class = 'numberCircleGreenShadow'>)[0-9](<\/span>));
    myNewText = myText.split(re);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
var myText = "<span id = 'sHint' class = 'numberCircleGreenShadow'>1</span>test1<span id = 'sHint' class = 'numberCircleGreenShadow'>2</span>test2";

var re = new RegExp(/<span id = 'sHint' class = 'numberCircleGreenShadow'>[0-9]+<\/span>/);
var myNewText = myText.split(re).filter(i => i);
```

Comment: It will return 3 items not 2.